# How to create master set of slides with relative inputs for sub set of slides?

Tags: beamer, input, relative

I am preparing a series of lectures using `Beamer` (both article mode and slides mode). My set of files looks something like this:

```
Lectures\
    article.tex
    slides.tex
    main.tex
    mainarticle.tex
    mainslides.tex
    Lecture1\
        main.tex
        article.tex
        slides.tex
    Lecture2\
        main.tex
        article.tex
        slides.tex
```

Both `slides.tex` and `article.tex` uses `\input{main}` in each of the stand alone lectures.

Now I would like to compile a "master" version of the lectures that simply includes all the standalone lectures. I am trying this in two ways:

1. In `Lecture/main.tex` I have:

   ```
    \input{Lecture1/main.tex}
    \input{Lecture2/main.tex}
   ```
2. In `Lectures/mainarticle.tex` I have:

   ```
    \includepdf[pages=-]{Lecture1/article.pdf}
    \includepdf[pages=-]{Lecture2/article.pdf}
   ```

   and in `Lectures/mainslides.tex` I have:

   ```
    \includepdf[pages=-]{Lecture1/slides.pdf}
    \includepdf[pages=-]{Lecture2/slides.pdf}
   ```

Each of these two options has a drawback:

1. In some of the lectures I use `InputVerbatim` from the `fancyvrb` package to include some source code files. When I compile the "master" article or slides, the source code file can't be found because the relative path doesn't exist as it does when compiling the standalone lecture.
2. The resulting `mainslides.pdf`has blank (white) pages where there should be the content of each of the lectures.

I would prefer to do option 1, but can live with option 2. Is this even possible?

Comment: To overcome the two different paths problem, you could use`\IfFileExists{}{}{}`: check if it is in one location, if yes use it here, if not use it from the other path.

Comment: I knew that this was a solved problem, I just didn't know where to start looking. This solved my problem! @samcarter if you create an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: done __________

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\IfFileExists` can help with the two choices for the path. A simple example:

```
\IfFileExists{./filename.pdf} %if the file exist in the current directory 
    {\includegraphic{./filename}} % use this file
    {\includegraphic{./Lecture2/filename}} % if not use from subfolder
```